# Controlling order of matched pattern in Notepad++ RegExps

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm having a somewhat hard time using RegExps in Notepad ++.
Like, in the text:

```
Something1 (some  thing2) (some-thing3) (some:thing4) something5
```

My pattern "\(.*\)" matches:`

```
(some  thing2) (some-thing3) (some:thing4)
```

(everything inside the first "(" and the last ")", absolutely)
How can i match: "(some  thing2)", "(some-thing3)" and "(some:thing4)" separately? (when you find a "(", keep matching until the next ")").

Comment: `"\(.*?\)" ` ..................

Answer (score 0):

Use a negated class between the brackets:

```
\([^()]*\)
```

[image]

If you do not want empty parentheses to be returned, just use `+` instead of `*`.

And in case you have nested `(...)` (as in `(some  (thing2))`), you may use

```
(\((?>[^()]|(?1))*\))
```

Comment: Does Notepad use PCRE ?

Comment: Yes, Notepad supports most PCRE features. Not all.